# finding out an idle time of an object

Tags: java

I need to calculate the idle time of an object let say i have a pojo of which an object is created in some other class shown below and in that class i have created the object but have not used it but later some how i decide to know the idle time of that object , please advise how can i calculate the idle time of that object..

lets say below is my pojo

```
public class Emp implements Comparable {

    String name, job;
    int salary;

    public Emp(String n, String j, int s) {
        this.name = n;
        this.job = j;
        this.salary = s;

    }

    public int hashcode() {
        return name.hashCode() + job.hashCode() + salary;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object o) {

        Emp e1 = (Emp) o;
        return this.name.equals(e1.name) && this.job.equals(e1.job) && this.salary == e1.salary;
    }


    // method have return type
    public int compareTo(Object o) {
        Emp e1 = (Emp) o;
        return this.name.compareTo(e1.name);//compareToIgnoreCase
    }




    public void display()
    {
      System.out.println(name+"\t"+job+"\t"+salary);
     }

}
```

now lets say there is another class

```
class Abc 
{

public static void main(String args[])
{

Emp e1 = new Emp();//created e1 object but not use it later on decided to find out its idle time

}
}
```

Comment: You want to find out how long it's been since some method in your class was called? For what purpose?

Comment: yeah i want to record the time the moment i have created e1 and later at any time point of time i wan to minus the current time with the time that it was created

Comment: OK, but why? I want to make sure you're asking the right question.

Comment: well somebody ask me and even i do not know at that time how to calculate the idle time tht is the time when object is created and still it is idle so for my own knowledge please i want to know

Comment: well, just when you created e1( in its constructor), save the current time in some variable of your program and later, whenever any other class is invoking e1's method, just subtract that time to get the idle time.

Comment: @AADTechnical Thanks a lot can you also please show in code how to achieve this Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Without using profiling tools, record the object creation time in the object's constructor, and keep track of the methods' execution times (e.g. by keeping a global execution timer within an object and aggregating the execution time every time a method completes).

Then, the object's idle time is (current time - object's creation time - total execution time for all the methods). For example:

```
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicLong;

public class Emp implements Comparable {

    String name, job;
    int salary;
    private AtomicLong busyTime;
    private long instantiationTime;

    public Emp(String n, String j, int s) {
        instantiationTime = System.nanoTime();
        this.name = n;
        this.job = j;
        this.salary = s;
    }

    public int hashcode() {
        long startTime = System.nanoTime();
        int returnValue = name.hashCode() + job.hashCode() + salary;
        busyTime.addAndGet(System.nanoTime() - startTime);
        return returnValue;
    }

    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        long startTime = System.nanoTime();
        Emp e1 = (Emp) o;
        boolean returnValue = this.name.equals(e1.name)
                && this.job.equals(e1.job) && this.salary == e1.salary;
        busyTime.addAndGet(System.nanoTime() - startTime);
        return returnValue;
    }

    // method have return type
    public int compareTo(Object o) {
        long startTime = System.nanoTime();
        Emp e1 = (Emp) o;
        int returnValue = this.name.compareTo(e1.name);
        busyTime.addAndGet(System.nanoTime() - startTime);
        return returnValue;// compareToIgnoreCase
    }

    public void display() {
        long startTime = System.nanoTime();
        System.out.println(name + "\t" + job + "\t" + salary);
        busyTime.addAndGet(System.nanoTime() - startTime);
    }

    public long getIdleTime() {
        return System.nanoTime() - instantiationTime - busyTime.get();
    }
}
```

Comment: The important thing is to use `System.nanoTime()` for this, as that is its intended purpose.

Comment: @Nick Thanks a lot can you also please show in code also how to achieve these things that will help more to clarify

Comment: @gabe - a couple years back I read about System.nanoTime() being broken on multicore systems. Is it still true?